# why jquery clear all field after close modal boostrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, modal-dialog, field

Hi i've a page with a modal bootstrap. When i hide the modal, i found all field of page caller cleared.

I've debugged code, and i saw when happened and is on jquery framework

this is the code of my modal

```
<div class="modal fade draggable-modal" id="modalContatto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" id="btnModalClose" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Ricerca Contatto</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @{ ContattoModelView cmv = new ContattoModelView();
                    cmv.ModeView = ContattoModelView.MODEVIEW.SEARCH;
                }                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Search/ContattoSearch.cshtml", cmv)
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnModalClose").on('click', function () {
                $('#modalContatto').modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: $('#modalContatto').modal('hide'); is the problem? Try: $('#modalContatto').hide(); Or is this not what you mean?

Comment: yes i mean it, but i've the sam result.

Comment: this is the code tha clear my field

                    getAllResponseHeaders: function() {
                        return 2 === t ? f : null
                    },


the code is into jquery.js